# applications shares same BDE

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, bde

I encouter problem with my application when it turn in PC running other application using same BDE as my application , my application can't store record in database in this case, is thre any configuration to make in BDE resolving this problem .

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Please edit your question to make it a bit more clear, so we can help you better. Do you get any error messages? If so, which ones? What kind of database is your data in? Paradox, dBase, Text, remote database? Where is your data stored? Same machine, remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

If you operating system is XP or Win7 try editing the BDE settings in BDE administrator in the control panel (backup you idapi.cfg first, of course!). Under configuration|system|init change the sharedmemlocation to 6BDE. Restart your computer.

This will allow BDE to be called by mulitple programs. It may allow the two programs to use the BDE.